# Recursively find and delete a folder using batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, recursion

I am trying to write a simple batch file which will recursively find and delete a folder. But the following script is not looking under sub folder. Wondering how to do that?

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\"
for /d %%i in (temp) do rd /s "%%i"
pause
```

Thanks!

Comment: The rd option to recurse uses a capital 'S'. That looks like a lower-case 's' in your script.

Comment: @neilh: Lower case /s works fine with most DOS/Windows commands from a prompt, unless the command uses upper and lower case to mean different things. In the case of `rd`, either case works the same.

Comment: Thanks guys, but tried both upper case (S) and upper case (RD) didn't help..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for /d /r "c:\" %%a in (temp\) do if exist "%%a" echo rmdir /s /q "%%a"
```

For each folder (`/d`), recursively (`/r`) under `c:\` test for the presence of a `temp` folder and if it exist, remove it

directory removal command is only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command

Comment: Thanks MC, I think this is working but small hiccup. When I run the following: @echo off
cd /d "C:\"
for /d /r "c:\" %%a in (temp1\) do if exist "%%a" echo rmdir /S /Q "%%a"
pause

Comment: Thanks MC, I think this is working but small hiccup. When I run the following: 

@echo off

for /d /r "c:\" %%a in (temp1\) do if exist "%%a" echo rmdir /S /Q "%%a"


It is just simulating but not deletig the "temp1" folder which are under c:


output:

C:\>c:\TestScripts\Good\Working\find_delete_temp_workarea.bat
rmdir /S /Q "c:\temp1\"
rmdir /S /Q "c:\test3\temp1\"
rmdir /S /Q "c:\tmp\temp1\"

Comment: @rasuajak, first, read the last line in the answer. Second, keep the ending backslash in the name of the folder to avoid `if exist` could match a file with the same name

Answer (score 0):

The `/S` switch to `rd` means

```
/S      Removes all directories and files in the specified directory
        in addition to the directory itself.  Used to remove a directory
        tree.
```

It does not mean it will search all directories looking for one with the specified name and delete them.

In other words, if you run `rd /S Test` from the `C:\Temp` folder, it will delete `C:\Temp\Test\*.*`, including all subdirectories (of any name) of `C:\Temp\Test`. It does **not** mean it will delete `C:\Temp\AnotherDir\Test`, because that isn't a subfolder of `C:\Temp\Test`.

Comment: Thanks but in the above example, what if I run the "rd /S Test" from C:\ instead of C:\Temp, doesn't it getrid of all the "Test" folders which are under C:\ ?

Comment: Then it will delete `C:\Test\*.*` and subfolders, but not `C:\Dummy\Test\`, just as I said. :-)